# Foursquare API : edit / Propose edit not working

Tags: foursquare

I am manager of the testing location.We're testing with the 'Propose Venue Edit' method and we're not seeing the name change with our test location.

I get this response from API

URL : https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/55c0b1ec498e7261dfb1e42c
/edit?v= 20150804&name=TESTING_HOTEL&oauth_token={token}

Request Paratmeter:
{
VENUE_ID: "55c0b1ec498e7261dfb1e42c",
name: "Testing Venue"
}

Response :
{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"woes":[]}}

Is there any verification required after update to reflect changes on venue OR Venue must be verified before update? I can able to perform edit Testing Venue, it is reflated instantly from web but not from Foursquare API.

Thanks,
Bhargav Kukadiya